# "Gnuplot terminal is not set stack traceback" in Eclipse LDT

Tags: eclipse, lua, gnuplot, torch

I am writting Torch programs in Eclipse (LDT for Lua). When I tired to use the function **gnuplot.figure()**, I got an error as *“Gnuplot terminal is not set”*. However, when I ran the same script using the terminal, the figures showed up perfectly.

I am using a mac and I have tried both gnuplot with qt and with x11. In both cases, Eclipse LDT does not work, but the terminal works fine.

Is there a way I can directly use gnuplot in Eclipse LDT?